# IBM Assistant - Why can't I check for an existing/set entity rather than checking by context variable?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have a Chatbot simulating an Online Floriculture. The user should be able to buy some flowers from it.

There are a few requirements:

1. It must use Slots to fill all values at once (without creating a huge tree);
2. It must accept two payment methods: credit card and cash.

If the payment method is **credit card**, then it must ask for the flag (Visa, Elo or Mastercard) before finishing the purchase. If the payment method is **cash**, then we just need to finish it.

I have the following nodes:

**Node tree:**

[image]

**#ComprarBuqueFlores details:**

[image]

In the tree, you guys can see I have two different nodes (children of *#ComprarBuqueFlores*) using two different techniques. The first node checks the **context variable**. The second one checks the **entity value**.

When I make a comparison between context variable values, it **works fine**. However, when I try to check the entity's value directly, it **doesn't work**, always evaluating to **false** (even when @FormaDePagamento is recognized as "dinheiro").

The screenshot below shows how it fails in such case:

[image]

The error happens because none of the children nodes evaluates to true, which means **@FormaDePagamento:dinheiro** is false even the Chatbot recognizing such value.

**So, the question is:**

What is the difference between comparing it to the context variable and comparing it to the recognized entity value? Why comparing to an entity value is not acceptable and evaluates to false in such a situation?

Comment: I don't see all the details but it could be because the context is saved to the variable, but the entity was detected in ComprarBuqueFlores and not in the subnode. There, it is a different evaluation context.

Comment: You may wish to try replacing the "Skip user input" jump to the child/sub nodes, and use a "conditional jump" to the child/sub nodes. With this type of jump Watson Assistant will process the parent node, then move to the sub-nodes and perform their conditional tests. This action is all done as one input step.Its not documented, but the "skip user input" may reset the user input message, thus entities would also be set to null. - You would need to test to confirm.